# C# BLE Read Error (Windows)

Tags: c#, arduino, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, uart

I am writing a C# application to connect and read data from an Adafruit Feather board.

I managed to successfully connect to the board using UWP APIs on Windows 10.
However I am getting an error when trying to do a Read on the UART Service offered by the Adafruit board.

The error is the following:

[image]

And occurs at this line in the code:

[image]

This is the code I am using. Apologies if it is still a bit messy - I will clean it once it works.

```
    Guid uart_uid = new Guid("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");
            Guid uart_read_uid = new Guid("6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");

            if (eventArgs.BluetoothAddress == 221661906381440)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Advertisement:"));
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  BT_ADDR: {0}", eventArgs.BluetoothAddress));
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  FR_NAME: {0}", eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName));
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Sensor found. Initiating connection...");
                Console.WriteLine();

                BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(221661906381440);
                GattDeviceService gatt_uart = device.GetGattService(uart_uid);

                IReadOnlyList<GattCharacteristic> read = gatt_uart.GetCharacteristics(uart_read_uid);

                GattReadResult result = await read.First().ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", result.Value);
            }
```

Is the error due to my C# code or is it because of the format of the data I am sending from the board?

This is the Adafruit code I use to write:

```
  if(recording){
    ble.print("AT+BLEUARTTX=");
    ble.print("Color Temp: "); ble.print(colorTemp, DEC); ble.print(" K.");
    ble.println("\n");
    if (! ble.waitForOK() ) {
      Serial.println(F("Failed to send?"));
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**

I added a try catch to look at the exception. This is what I got.
[image]

**EDIT 2:**

These are the libraries I am using for C# and the Adafruit board respectively.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile;

#include <Wire.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "Adafruit_BLE.h"
#include "Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI.h"
#include "Adafruit_BluefruitLE_UART.h"
#include "Adafruit_TCS34725.h"
#include "BluefruitConfig.h"
```

Any help is appreciated,
**Thank you**

Comment: How about a try catch around the entire code and looking at the exception? What library are you using for the serial connection?

Comment: I've added a screenshot for the try catch and the libraries I am using. I'm having a hard time figuring this one out since the Microsoft documentation says nothing about exceptions thrown by the GATT classes...